# CodeIgniter Login using google openid

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to CodeIgniter framework. I have tried login using openid for that i copied lightopenid url and put it in config/config.php

```
$config['base_url']    = 'https://gitorious.org/lightopenid/lightopenid/raw/9d42dc24e4dd34121c98a6491bc3ef7933a68a19:openid.php';

A PHP Error was encountered

    Severity: Warning

    Message: require(openid.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

    Filename: models/login_model.php

    Line Number: 2
```

please find below the code i used

Controllers/loginGoogle.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class LoginGoogle extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('login_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        require_once 'openid.php';
        $openid = new LightOpenID("localhost");
        $openid->identity = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id';
        $openid->required = array(
            'namePerson/first',
            'namePerson/last',
            'contact/email',
            'birthDate', 
            'person/gender',
            'contact/postalCode/home',
            'contact/country/home',
            'pref/language',
            'pref/timezone',  
        );


    $openid->returnUrl = 'http://localhost/login_thirdparty/codeigniterlogin/index.php/logingoogle/loginAuth';



        $data['openid'] = $openid;
        $this->load->view('googleLoginView', $data);
    }

    public function loginAuth()
    {
        $this->login_model->index();
    }
}
```

models/login_model.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
require 'openid.php';

class Login_model extends CI_Model 
{
    public function index()
    {
        $openid = new LightOpenID("localhost");

        if($openid->mode)
        {
            if($openid->mode == 'cancel')
            {
                echo "User has canceled authentication !";
            }
            elseif($openid->validate())
            {
                $data = $openid->getAttributes();
                $email = $data['contact/email'];
                $first = $data['namePerson/first'];

                echo "Identity : $openid->identity <br />";
                echo "Email : $email <br />";
                echo "First name : $first";
                echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); echo "</pre>";


            }
            else
            {
                echo "The user has not logged in";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Go to the login page to logged in";
        }
    }
}
```

views/googleLoginView.php

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Login using google account</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href = "<?php echo $openid->authUrl(); ?>" > Loging Using google account </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cause of error is  `require 'openid.php';` .you didnt put openid.php file or cannt find that file in both model and controller classes.

you better to do, make a folder in source file directly (in netbeans) as openid folder and make a php file on it. and copy the code of following link and paste it in that blank php file you have created.

https://gitorious.org/lightopenid/lightopenid/raw/9d42dc24e4dd34121c98a6491bc3ef7933a68a19:openid.php

and in both controller and model you have to change `require 'openid.php'` into `require "opened/openid.php"`

hope it works